# I want to add csrf_field() in javascript laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.4

```
(function () {
        new _vue2.default({
            el: 'body',

            data: {
                tableData: {
                    options: {
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: true,
                        pageCount: 10
                    },

                    columns: [{
                        value: 'id',
                        text: 'No',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: false
                    }, {
                        value: 'name',
                        text: 'Name',
                        sortable: false,
                        editable: false,
                        isHTML: true
                    }, {
                        value: 'items',
                        text: '#of Items',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: false
                    }, {
                        value: 'total',
                        text: 'Total',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: false
                    },  {
                        value: 'click',
                        text: '',
                        sortable: false,
                        editable: false,
                        isHTML: true
                    },],

                    rows: [],

                    onPageChanged: function onPageChanged(page) {
                        console.log('Current page is ' + page);
                    }
                }
            },

            ready: function ready() {
                console.log(invoice.length);
                var invoices = invoice;
                var length = invoice.length;

                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    var obj = {
                        id: {
                            value: i + 1
                        },

                        name: {
                            value: '<a href="update/'+ invoices[i].id + '">' + invoices[i].invoice + '</a>'

                        },

                        items: {
                            value: invoices[i].items ,

                        },

                        total: {
                            value: invoices[i].alltotal ,

                        },



                        click: {
                            value: '<a href="pdf/'+ invoices[i].id + '">PDF</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;  <form method="POST" action="remove/'+ invoices[i].id + '"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"><button type="submit">Remove</button></form>'
                        },
                    };

                    this.tableData.rows.push(obj);
                }
            },


            components: {
                DataTable: _DataTable2.default
            }
        });
    })();
```

I want to create delete form in click:{} because I want to use rout delete function in laravel 5.4.
My html table is built with vue.js.So I need to write html code in vue.js. I get this error (TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:). If anyone know please answer me.

Comment: you need to post with laravel token.

Comment: yes I know. But I don't know how to call csrf_field() in delete form(click:{}).

Answer (score 1):

First, add `{{ csrf_token() }}` in your page.

Then add the following line in your delete form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="' + document.getElementsByName('_token')[0].value + '">
```

Comment: Or you could just use `{!! csrf_field() !!}` which generates the field for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Comment: this is my index.blade.php

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
      
</head>
<body>
    <div class="panel-body" id="app">
    <data-table :data-table="tableData"></data-table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var invoice = {!! json_encode($invoice->toArray()) !!};
    
   
    </script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/vueapp.js')}}"></script>
    </div>

</body>

</html>`